# About Poincare section for the double pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, chaos-theory, complex-systems

I am reading Prof. Louis N. Hand's *Analytical Mechanics.* In the chapter about chaos, it introduces the concepts of [Poincare section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map) based on the example of double pendulum. Also, it plot the section when the initial angles for the upper and lower pendulum is small (about 1 degree for each). So in this case, the section contains some closed curves. I have few questions about the section.

1. Firstly, is it possible for some curves shown in the section crossing? Why and why not?
2. Secondly, in the plot it shows in the book (fig. 11.4), there are two fix points but they are not symmetric about the generalized momentum. Why is that?

Following the post found in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40122/, I have the code modified such that

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**. Yes, it is possible for the curves in Poincare section to cross. (I am assuming you mean generally). Remember, that Poincare section is a 2D projection of a 3D section of a 4D phase space. Regular, non-chaotic dynamics correspond to the winding of a $T_2$ torus embedded in this 4D space. Sections of such torus could be the couple of closed curves in the 3D hyperplane. Projecting this hyperplane on the 2D space could produce intersections. Additionally, Poincare section may include only points with a given directions of a hypersurface crossing, then the number of resulting curves would be reduced. Probably even then there still is a possibility for the intersecting curves in the Poincare section, although those would require highly nonlinear regimes (possibly after at least one bifurcation).

**Second**. Why would you expect the symmetry with respect to sign of the momentum? The Hamiltonian for the double pendulum contains the term proportional to the product of both momenta $l_\alpha l_\beta$. Therefore Hamiltonian and the torus in the 4D phase space are invariant only with respect to change of signs of both momenta,
but not with respect to a change of sign of a single momentum.  After making cross-section and projecting it onto 2D plane, no mirror symmetry w.r.t. momentum sign is to be expected in the resulting Poincare section.

**Addition** Upon discussion in the comments, I understand that the one unresolved issue is the set of initial data which generates the figure from the book. 
In the book the figure is accompanied by the comment:

> To produce Figure 11.4 and all subsequent Poincare sections, 
>   the initial conditions are varied. The total energy has the value $E = H(\alpha(0), 0, -\alpha(0), 0)$.

So, all those curves correspond to different sections arising from varied ICs with the fixed energy $E_0$. Here is my attempt at reproducing the figure:

[image: Poincare sections]

Various colors correspond to an individual Poincare section defined by its own initial point. The point are chosen so that:
$$
\alpha=0, \quad \beta=0, \quad \dot{\alpha}>0, \quad H(0,l_\alpha,0,l_\beta)=E_0.
$$
The value of $l_\beta$ is chosen so that curves are evenly spaced between two limiting points corresponding to normal modes of oscillation. The last two conditions and known $l_\beta$ allow us to unambiguously calculate $l_\alpha$.

Finally, the limiting curve is defined by the equations:
$$
\alpha=0, \quad \dot{\alpha}=0, \quad H(0,l_\alpha,0,l_\beta)=E_0.
$$

The code for the picture is based on the linked question from Mathematica SE and can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/5A4zpN8r).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If we apply small angle approximation, should the curves in Poincare section representing the periodic motion so should not show any crossing, is that right? As for the symmetry, I don't quite understand that. The reason is I plot the section with matlab and other code found online, I see the symmetry.

Comment: "No crossings" apply only to a full phase space. Producing Poincare section involves making a *projection* on a hyperplane, and this *could* produce intersections. (This is generally speaking, I do not know if hyperplane $\alpha=0$, with projection on $(\beta, l_\beta)$-plane from the book would produce intersections).

Comment: The symmetry of the plot obviously depends on the initial conditions. My hypothesis is in your simulation you use ICs with some zero initial values. I suggest to use several starting points compatible with a given value of energy.

Comment: To plot the curves in the Poincare sections, I vary the initial conditions so to observe different curves. You may see the result here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40122/help-to-plot-poincare-section-for-double-pendulum#40126, in the question post, the result from the book enclosed and in the replies, there show the plot in mathematica, there is symmetry observed.

Comment: Ah! The mirror symmetry in these figures is because  points both with $\dot{\alpha} >0$ and $\dot{\alpha}<0$ are plotted. Figure from @belisarius includes condition $l_\alpha>0$ (which for small angles is equivalent to $\dot{\alpha}>0$) and does not possess such a symmetry.

Comment: Thanks. That's good hint. I copy belisarius's code and run it, it does show the plot without such a symmetry. But in the bottom half (where $l_\beta<0$), I didn't see those close curves like that shown in the book or in the figure enclosed in the question thread. So is that any other condition I should impose to reproduce exact same plot like in the book?

Comment: Correction, $l_\alpha>0$ is *not* the same as $\dot{\alpha}>0$. So you should replace that condition with $(l_\alpha - (1 + \cos \beta) l_\beta) > 0$. This will produce the full curve (without crossing). Another point: in the book the ICs were varied in such a way, that the total energy remained constant. So you should choose ICs (for example) like this: $\alpha=0,\,\beta=0$,  $l_\beta$ is arbitrary (it would correspond to the curve crossing vertical axis of symmetry) while $l_\alpha$ is chosen so that the total energy is $E$.

Comment: Thanks. I modified the code based on your reply. And change the ICs based on the book. In the book, it is said that $\alpha(0)=-\beta(0)=1^\circ$, the constant energy is $E=H(\alpha(0), 0, -\alpha(0), 0) \simeq -2.9996953903127825$ But I find that if I fix the energy as above, $l_\alpha$ is solved to be complex. So I add a small offset to the constant energy, gives $E\simeq -2.9985953903127824$, it then plots something as shown in the edited post. But it is still not quite same as the figure shown in the book (see below)

Comment: First, the bottom fix point in the book is about -0.01 but in my plot, it shifted up to -0.02. Secondly, in my result, the biggest closed curve in the second half cross the $l_\alpha$ axis at about 0.018 but in the book, it crosses at about 0.07.

Comment: I tried many different energy, finally find that when the constant energy chosen as -2.9996992384564987, it gave the plot pretty close to the one shown in the book. So does it mean the fix point really depends on the energy chosen? My last question is in the book, there should the big circle as the boundary, how to find and plot that boundary?

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: I think I understand most of that now but one of your comment there you said $\dot{\alpha}$ is not same as $l_\alpha$? So the time derivative of angle is not angular momentum?

Comment: Of course. $\dot{\alpha}$ is calculated from the Hamilton's equations: $\dot{\alpha}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial l_\alpha}=\frac{2(l_\alpha - (1 + \cos \beta) l_\beta)}{3 - \cos 2\beta}$ which is obviously different from the $l_\alpha$. The quantities $\dot{\alpha}$ and $l_\alpha$ are related to each other via Legendre transformation.

Comment: I think I confuse the change of angle over time with the angular momentum. Actually, it should be angular speed instead of angular momentum. So $\dot{\alpha}$ is angular speed and $l_\alpha$ is angular momentum, right? So can we calculate the Poincare section by restrict that $l_\alpha>0$? If so, does it make any sense to do so physically?

Comment: Right. And condition $\dot{\alpha}>0$ makes sense because it restricts the direction of the intersection of the curve in the 4D space with the hyperplane $\alpha=0$ (see fig. 11.3 in the book). I do not think that imposing the restriction $l_\alpha>0$ has similar clear interpretation.

Comment: Hi there, I have another question regarding the double pendulum. In the plot you made, there is two fixed points shown in positive and negative region of $l_\beta$. I am wondering in what way I can calculate those fixed points? Should I solve the equations of $\dot{\alpha}=0, \dot{\beta}=0, \dot{l_\alpha}=0, \dot{l_\beta}=0$? The equations seem too complicated and I don't find a way to solve it.

Comment: I seen that the fixed point is plotted in the Poincare section, so to find the fixed point, should I simply replace $\alpha$ with zero and make $\dot{l_\alpha}=0$ and solve for $\beta$ and $l_\beta$? I did that and solve it numerically, but it gives me a solution with $l_\beta=0$ and $\beta$ is non zero. However, if you read the plot the fixed point should locate around $(\beta=0, l_\beta=-0.01)$ and $(\beta=0, l_\beta=0.024)$

Comment: The 'fixed points' of yours correspond to the torus in phase space degenerating to a curve. It means that of the two possible modes of oscillations only one is excited. (Each of the points corresponding to its own mode). To calculate them in the case of small angles (like we have here) just linearize the equations and find its normal modes, then by setting the energy of each of the modes to $E_0$ you would obtain the two phase space trajectories which produce two singular points in the Poincare section.

Comment: So can I say fixed point always corresponding to regular motion and is that the reason why I have to linearize the map? So based on your description, it seems that fixed point depends on energy also or it always gives when energy is the lowest energy?

Comment: This singular point on Poincare section corresponds to a special kind of regular motion: stable periodic orbit. I suggested linearization just for convenience (and to obtain analytical result) for small angles. These points would still be there at greater energies, even when one cannot ignore nonlinear corrections (but there would generally be no closed form expression for them then).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand it a bit more now. I read a book today about finding the fixed point mathematically. There the author just try to solve the differential equation when all time derivative of each generalized coordinates to zero with linearization. So in our case, I linearize all angle but from the second equation $l_\alpha'=0$, I obtain that $\alpha=\beta=0$ and then plug that back to the last equation but I will get null solution for $l_\beta$. I understand that we could solve it from normal mode but what's wrong with this math?